# Mouse stutters, but trackpad is smooth

Tags: 11.04, usb, mouse

On my Dell Latitude E6410, several USB mice I tried are often "stuttery", but the trackpad is always working fine.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I sometimes see this if I don't have the device plugged in when I boot. Do you have the mice plugged in on boot? (I have an E6510).

Comment: I thought so, but I'll pay attention to this. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I'm a chinese student, my English is not well, but I really know how to deal this problem.
This problem is worked in ACPI，you can edit grub by terminal to change it:

```
cd /etc/default
sudo cp grub grub.backup (just in case it goes wrong)
sudo gedit grub
```

change this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

for this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noacpi"
```

save, then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and if wireless out of work，you can edit:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=force"
```

I hope I can help you, excuse me, my English is so bad, I will learn it try my best. haha~

Comment: +1 good answer and your English is perfect,  don't worry.

Answer (score 2):

Might sound stupid, but have you tried looking at the surface where you're trying to use the mouse on? In my experience, optical mice can respond very different to various surfaces.

Comment: No, it's not the surface - The mice I tried work perfectly on the same surface when using Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

I concur, I have similar problems on my E6410. Attaching the mouse after booting results in very slow response. Sometimes even booting with the mouse causes this. It seems to be a timing issue with the way things are initialized.